# Create flutter color map with a increasing index

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create a 100 map with same values but with a increasing index?

I need to follow this structure

```
    Map btnmap = {
  "0": {
    "a": Colors.grey[800],
    "b": Colors.grey[800],
    "c": Colors.grey[800],
    "d": Colors.grey[800],
    "s": false,
  },
  "1": {
    "a": Colors.grey[800],
    "b": Colors.grey[800],
    "c": Colors.grey[800],
    "d": Colors.grey[800],
    "s": false,
  },
  "2": {
    "a": Colors.grey[800],
    "b": Colors.grey[800],
    "c": Colors.grey[800],
    "d": Colors.grey[800],
    "s": false,
  }, [...]
```

I am trying this way doing some research

```
    Map<String,Color>  btnMap = {
        "a": Colors.grey[800],
        "b": Colors.grey[800],
        "c": Colors.grey[800],
        "d": Colors.grey[800],
       }

var list = List<Map>.filled(100, btnMap);
```

but that doesn't solve my problem as I can't have a growing ++ index for each one, how can I fix that? thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you want to have can be achieved with collection `for`:

```dart
final btnmap = {
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) '$i': {
    "a": Colors.grey[800],
    "b": Colors.grey[800],
    "c": Colors.grey[800],
    "d": Colors.grey[800],
    "s": false,
  },
};
```

[Learn more about collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#lists).